# Can the US president reside somewhere else than the White House?

Tags: united-states, president

Could President-Elect Trump decide to reside in somewhere else (NY for example) when he becomes president ?

I understand that the White House is the official residence and has been "bunkerized" for safety and security, but is there a law that say president have to be there ?

Comment: Do you want him to [drive the escalator](https://youtu.be/2W_yGWPrC20?t=7) continuously the next four years? ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Precedent for a sitting President not residing in the White House?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13617/precedent-for-a-sitting-president-not-residing-in-the-white-house)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can the US president reside somewhere else than the White House?

#### Yes, they can.

There are **no requirements** that the President **must** live in the White House. However, since the White House has command centres, it wouldn't be convenient for the President at all if they choose not to live there.

---

> [...] is there a law that say president have to be there ?

#### No, there isn't such law.

The [Compensation of the President](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/102) states that:

> He shall be **entitled** also to the use of the furniture and other effects belonging to the United States and kept in the Executive Residence at the White House.
>
> *(emphasise mine)*

The keyword is 'entitled', so it's up to the President to decide if they want to live there. However, even if it's legal, it doesn't mean that it's feasible.

Comment: I don't think the Secret Service would be too happy about trying to secure another residence in the same manner that the White House is secured, however. Is there any provision for the Secret Service to temporarily 'force' the President to live in a 'secure' location while they prepare his chosen residence?

Comment: During the renovations to the White House (1949 - 1952) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Reconstruction, the President shifted to Blair House across the street from the White House..