# Precedent for a sitting President not residing in the White House?

Tags: united-states, history, president

Was there ever any precedent set, for a sitting President of the United States to not have resided in the White House during the entirety or parts of his tenure ?
**Note** : Other than when it was destroyed by fire (1929) or due to war (1812)

Comment: I assume other than when it was destroyed by fire (1929)  or war (1812) ?

Comment: @Max: Yes, I've edited the question as well.

Comment: Bush did spend about a year and a half on "vacation" away from the White House, and that doesn't include time spent abroad on official business, but I don't think that's what artfdviuyt is driving at.

Comment: Does moving across the street during renovations count?

Comment: Washington never lived there, because it wasn't built until after he left office (and died). https://www.whitehousehistory.org/questions/who-was-the-only-president-not-to-live-in-the-white-house

Comment: See also http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/13297/1370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the White House is used as an *official residence* there is no law that **requires** him to actually live there. It is provided as a convenience and courtesy to the president so that he does not have to commute or use his own money for a residence. The building also is set up so that the president has full office capabilities and security. Otherwise, the secret service would have to build security into whatever building the president moved into, find locations to staff the guard posts and build in the full communications technology.

Comment: It's true that the white house is probably similar to a nuclear submarine on the inside, in terms of technology, and there is a huge military presence throughout the white house, it must be like being the guest of nato central command, which is a bit of a crap setting for a national leader. Technically speaking, a president could also rule the country with a secure PC and phone, and aboard air force one, and have a low technology palace of reception, with a good perimieter.

Comment: I would expect outcry from the taxpayers if a president decided to live in another place because they preferred it to the White House, especially if that is outside of DC.

Comment: This does not answer the question; it reads more like a comment.

Answer (score 3):

President Truman lived in the Blair House for a while because the White House was being renovated.